# failing a XCTestCase with assert without the test continuing to run but without stopping other tests

Tags: xcode, xctest

I'm trying to test my application using the XCTest framework.

I want my single test case to fail if some logical condition holds (using an assertion).
I don't want the rest of the code in the test case to run, because this might lead to problems (access to null pointers, for example)
I also want the rest of the test case to run normally, and just the failed test to be marked as failed.

I've noticed XCTestCase has a property called continueAfterFailure. 
However, setting it to YES caused the failed test to continue executing lines after the assertion, and setting it to NO caused the rest of the tests not to run at all.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pascal's answer gave me the idea to achieve this properly. XCTool now behaves like OCUnit when an assertion fails: the execution of the test case is aborted immediately, tearDown invoked and the next test case is run.

Simply override the method `invokeTest` in your base class (the one that inherits from the XCTestCase class):

```
- (void)invokeTest
{
    self.continueAfterFailure = NO;

    @try
    {
        [super invokeTest];
    }
    @finally
    {
        self.continueAfterFailure = YES;
    }
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Weird but doesn't work in Xcode 9. It still does continue execution after `XCTFail`.

Comment: Even on Xcode 14.0.1 changing self.continueAfterFailure to false on-demand around critical sections of assertions you definitely don't want the test to continue if failures occur (whereas the remainder of the test should have self.continueAfterFailure = true), doesn't seem to always works (almost like the test runner only occasionally checks the flag). The section of assertions I was trying to force self.continueAfterFailure = false around were in an "async" func call so perhaps that is causing some issues?

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to add:

```
continueAfterFailure = false
```

into setUp() method. So it will look like this:

**Swift**

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    continueAfterFailure = false
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
 - (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    [self setContinueAfterFailure:NO];
}
```

Comment: In the Objective-C, you should be using NO instead of FALSE.

Comment: In objC you can use TRUE/FALSE or YES/NO, it doesn't change a thing, it's only a syntactic thing.

Comment: Sure, but you could also say 0 and 1, but we don't since the proper ObjC is YES/NO. Sure it works, go ahead and use it, just know that I won't be the only one to correct it.

Comment: You should also set `continueAfterFailure` to `true` inside `tearDown()`, or all testing will stop after a single failure.

Comment: From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496260-continueafterfailure) :  "`continueAfterFailure` - A Boolean value indicating whether the test case should continue running after a failure occurs.".  Its related only to single "test case" not all available tests in class.

Answer (score 8):

One option would be to check the condition normally, then fail and return from the test if it is false.

Something like this:

```
if (!condition) {
  XCTFail(@"o noes");
  return;
}
```

You could wrap this up in a helper macro to preserve readability.

BDD test libraries like [Kiwi](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi) are more elegant for this sort of thing, as they make it easier to share setup between many tests which leads to fewer assertions per test.

Comment: +1 I think this is the only way, other than replicating all the `XCTAssertXxx` macros.

Comment: It's not the only way, check the other answers for a much better approach.

Answer (score 5):

I am able to use `continueAfterFailure` and let the other tests run by using this pattern:

```
self.continueAfterFailure = NO;
@try
{
    // Perform test code here
}
@finally
{
    self.continueAfterFailure = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I've used it to make a better answer which does not require changing the code of the test cases. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift projects, I use a helper function (defined in a shared superclass of all my tests which itself extends `XCTestCase`):

```swift
/// Like `XCTFail(...)` but aborts the test.
func XCTAbortTest(_ message: String, 
                  file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line
                 ) -> Never {
    self.continueAfterFailure = false
    XCTFail(message, file: file, line: line)
    fatalError("never reached")
}
```

As the comment suggests, the call to `fatalError` is never actually executed; `XCTFail` aborts the test in an orderly fashion (`tearDown` is called, next test runs, etc.). The call is only there to trick the compiler into accepting `Never` as return type since `XCTFail` returns `Void` (it *does* return if `continueAfterFailure == true`).

Note that `self.continueAfterFailure` is reset to the default `true` for every test method. You can also make that explicit in `setUp()`.

Comment: I looked into my failures, it looks like sometimes when running tests with xcodebuild, the test doesn't stop on the XCTFail, and will crash the runner on fatalError. I am not able to reproduce this via Xcode though. :( I am setting continueAfterFailure=False

Comment: @yuf Interesting; I've never tried to run the tests from the CLI. Different behaviour there would probably be a bug? :/